# how to correctly pattern match with routers handleFunc?

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using gorilla web toolkit and golang, and have the following code

```
func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("test was called ..")
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    mx := mux.NewRouter()
    mx.HandleFunc(?, test)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mx)
}
```

My server will serve a html-document with a form that will do a get-request and send a "/?id={something}". How can I set up a pattern in the mx.HandleFunc to match the query so that test is called?

I have tried:

```
"/?id={something}, 
"/?id=", 
mx.HandleFunc("/", test).Queries("id")
mx.HandleFunc("/", test).Methods("POST")
```

(the last one I changed the corresponding page code so that form makes a post instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.Queries()` you need to give it both a key and a value, like:

```
mx.HandleFunc("/", test).Queries("id", "value")
```

You can also use a pattern as the value, like:

```
mx.HandleFunc("/", test).Queries("id", "{id:[0-9]+}")
```

See here for details: http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Queries

Comment: I have read the godoc, and tried this: mx.HandleFunc("/", test).Queries("id", "bar"). I print the r.URL.String() from the request, and get "/?id=bar", but it only goes to frontPage-func (mx.HandleFunc("/", frontPage). I expected it to go call test() since it was a query or both test() a frontPage() since it fits both patterns..

Comment: Ahhh, I think I know what is happening. It is a ordering of the handleFuncs that is the problem. I have the default case "/" first (which also matches (and catches) "/?id=")) so by changing the order it works, anyway thank you.